# How would you prove if $ab|(a+b)(a+b+1)$, then $(a,b) \leq \sqrt{a+b}$ for positive integers $a$ and $b$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, inequality, gcd-and-lcm

How would you prove if $ab|(a+b)(a+b+1)$, then $(a,b) \leq \sqrt{a+b}$ for positive integers $a$ and $b$?

My thoughts: I tried squaring both sides of $(a,b) \leq \sqrt{a+b}$ but don't know what to do with $(a,b)^2$ afterwards. I thought maybe using $\sqrt{ab} \leq \sqrt{(a+b)(a+b+1)} = \sqrt{(a+b)^2 + (a+b)}$ would help but I don't see how I could use it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Dzoooks Could you please give a hint on how to use $(a,b)^2 \leq ab$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $a$ and $b$ are positive integers satisfying $ab|(a+b)(a+b+1)$. Set $gcd(a,b)=x$, and set $a_x = a/x$, and $b_x=b/x$. Note that $xa_x = a$ and $xb_x=b$. Note also that $(a_x,b_x)=1.$ Since $$ab|(a+b)(a+b+1)$$ one has $$x^2a_xb_x|(xa_x + xb_x)(xa_x + xb_x +1)$$ which implies that 
$$xa_xb_x|(a_x + b_x)(xa_x + xb_x +1).$$ Now note that $gcd(x,xa_x + xb_x +1)=1$ so the previous relation forces $x|a_x+b_x$. We have then $$x \leq a_x + b_x = \frac{a}{x} + \frac{b}{x}.$$ One has then from clearing $x$ in the denominator 
$$x^2 \leq a+b$$ which implies the desired inequality.

Note that from a similar argument you can actually get a lower bound on $x$ and obtain that $$x \geq \sqrt{\frac{ab}{a+b+1}}.$$ So the actual possible range for the gcd is pretty tiny.

I'm highly curious where this problem came from. It isn't one I've seen before.

Comment: It's actually from a Maryam Mirzakhani book(which unfortunately is only available in my language, Persian) about number theory for IMO

Answer (score 2):

Let $d=gcd(a,b)$. Then, $d|a+b$ and hence $gcd(d,a+b+1)=1$.

This gives $gcd(d^2,a+b+1)=1$.

Now, you have 
$$d^2|ab|(a+b)(a+b+1) \,  \mbox{ and }\, gcd(d^2, a+b+1)=1 \Rightarrow d^2|a+b$$

This gives you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $(a,b)=x$, then we have $x^2 · \frac{ab}{x^2}|(a+b)(a+b+1)$
Since we have (a+b,a+b+1)=1, we can say that $x^2|(a+b)$ or $x^2|(a+b+1)$.
 If there exists a number t such that $t^2|(a+b)$ and $\frac{x^2}{t^2}|(a+b+1)$ (or reversely)
then $(a,b)=tx$ which contradicts to the former assumption,
then we have the conclusion by rooting($\sqrt{x^2}$). 
 Because this is my first time to answer question, there might be some mistakes in describing or showing the formula, I still hope that my answer can help you to solve this problem.

Comment: I don't think this works. In particular, one cannot conclude that either $x^2|a+b$ or $x^2 |a+b+1$. This would be valid if $x$ was a power of a prime,  but there's no reason that it couldn't split pieces up this way.

Comment: That said, it seems like the core of your idea can be made to work. See my answer.